# Changing an UIScrollview method to allow loading of views with images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, nsarray

How would you change this method to allow images to be in via an array rather than colors? As I have mySQL database which passing in urls which are assigned as NSStrings in xcode which are stored in an array.

Idea being that each view has set background image from the mySQL database.

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor blueColor],
                               [UIColor greenColor],[UIColor yellowColor] , nil];

            for (int i = 0; i < colors.count; i++) {

                CGRect frame;
                frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
                frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

                self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

                UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
                subview.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:i];

                [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];
            }

            self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * colors.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

    }
```

I made a try with (introNames is class where id and names of images are held from the mySQL database. The imageArray was created in the above code class and nsstrings from introNames were assigned to it).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    for (int i = 0; i < imageArray.count; i++) {

        introImages *snap = [imageArray objectAtIndex:i];

        imageName2 = snap.imageName;

        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

        self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

        UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName2]];

        [subview addSubview:backgroundView];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];
    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * imageArray.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

}
```

This is the working data retrieval system.

```
-(void) retrieveData
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataUrl];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    if (data) {

        jsonConnection = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
        imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonConnection.count; i++)
        {
            NSString *pID = [[jsonConnection objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
            NSString *pName = [[jsonConnection objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ImagesURL"];

            introImages *myImages = [[introImages alloc]initWithimageID:pID andimageName:pName];

            [imageArray addObject:myImages];
        }

    }

    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Something is wrong with your internet connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }
```

Any ideas would be great :)

Comment: I'd say to create strings with the filename(s) and just do NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName1], [UIImage imageNamed:imageName2], nil]; etc....

Comment: Was thinking that, but scared of not having the power of flexibility with changing the images remotely.

Comment: So what happened when you tried with IntroImages class?

Comment: Solved the problem. I pull the images from a set NSArray, with 6 values passed in. Opposed to having data passed in by the mySQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using iOS6+ in you app use this class [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView)
and if you are using iOS6 and above use [UICollectionView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html)